# jquery do double firing code on Focusout in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jquery, I need to get every event on input focus out

This my code.js

```
var checkFocusout = "";
    $("input").on("focusout", function(){

        checkFocusout = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log(checkFocusout);
    });
```

This my form
[image]

First I enter a value in the first input.
[image]

This my console in the browser

[image]

It should be like this.

But, I enter value to a second input

[image]

And this console on a browser.

[image: avas]

In console should do one time, but it does double time

My html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Number of Adult</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="number" name="noa_2" class="form-control text-right" value="0"
                                         onchange="calculatePrice(2)" price="111"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Number of Child</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="number" name="noc_2" class="form-control text-right" value="0"
                                         onchange="calculatePrice(2)" price="222"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Number of Infant</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="number" name="noi_2" class="form-control text-right" value="0"
                                         onchange="calculatePrice(2)" price="0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Discounts</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="number" name="d_2" class="form-control text-right" value="0"
                                         onchange="calculatePrice(2)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Total</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="number" name="t_2" readonly="" class="form-control text-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Vat</label>
            <div class="input-group col-sm-8">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">%</div>
                </div>
                <input type="number" name="v_2" class="form-control text-right" value="7" onchange="calculatePrice(2)">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Net Total</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="number" name="nt_2" readonly="" class="form-control text-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My full function javascript

```
function calculatePrice(product_id) {
    var noa = parseInt($('input[name="noa_'+product_id+'"]').val());
    var noc = parseInt($('input[name="noc_'+product_id+'"]').val());
    var noi = parseInt($('input[name="noi_'+product_id+'"]').val());
    var total_pax = (noa+noc+noi)+parseInt(available_of_product[product_id]);
    var vat = parseInt($('input[name="v_'+product_id+'"]').val());
    var t = parseInt($('input[name="t_'+product_id+'"]').val());
    var nt = parseInt($('input[name="nt_'+product_id+'"]').val());
    var public_adult = parseInt($('input[name="noa_'+product_id+'"]').attr('price'));
    var public_child = parseInt($('input[name="noc_'+product_id+'"]').attr('price'));
    var public_infant = parseInt($('input[name="noi_'+product_id+'"]').attr('price'));
    var number_of_pax = $("#available_span_"+product_id).attr('number_of_pax');
    var checkFocusout = "";


    $("input").on("keyup", function(){

        checkFocusout = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log(checkFocusout);
    });
    if (total_pax > number_of_pax){
        $("#alertMessageBody").html('<p>The number of passengers exceeds the maximum number of products.</p>');
        $('#alertMessage').modal('show')
    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: As it is it is an X/Y problem. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need focusout? Perhaps another event is more useful

Comment: I need to get input name on every edit value on the input form.

Comment: the problem is `focusout`, just use `focus` event.

Comment: @Gowri I think he knows that, its actual problem is the double firing. Is `focusout` the best event to listen. Why not maybe a `onchange` or `keyup`?

Comment: or input or blur

Comment: @guillaumepotier  I try both event listen, It still doubles firing.

Comment: @storyks this is strange, are you sure you did not bind events twice? Is this all your javascript code that you posted here?

Comment: I updated my code .

Comment: Yes, you're adding the event each time you call the function `calculatePrice`. One solution is add `$("input").off("keyup");` in the first lines of your function.

Comment: $("input").off("keyup", function(){

        checkFocusout = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log(checkFocusout);
    }); Not working

Comment: @Roy It not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
$("input").unbind().on("focusout", function(event){
        console.log(i)
        checkFocusout = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log(checkFocusout);
        i=i+1
    });
```

i hope it will work for you